# bx cr push command fails

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

I am following the documentation at 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/index.html#registry_images_pushing

But Unable to push image to IBM container registry

**1. Login to container service **

```
bx cr login
Logging in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'...
FAILED
Failed to 'docker login' to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net' with error: WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
.
```

Comment: Please provide details on your environment (OS, CLI version, Docker version). This is to make sure everything is up-to-date. See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/ts_index.html#ts_login

Comment: Check whether docker is running with `docker ps` command

Answer (score 0):

That, specifically the line: `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`, indicates that your docker daemon is not able to open a connection to the registry.

This is a network problem, you'll need to look into why you can't open this connection. `nc -zv registry.ng.bluemix.net 443` should succeed and `curl -v https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v2/` should return 401 UNAUTHORIZED.